# Hi, why is this returning typeError, but this is not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

const cartItems = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "ADD_TO_CART" :
      /** expecting action.id
       * fetching from state.shopItems with id*/ 
      return { ...state,  
        // [action.id]:{ amt: state[action.id].amt + 1 || 1 } 
        [action.id] : state[action.id] + 1 || 1 
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Hi, so I want to return { someID: { amt : 1} }.
I'm defining a key ID with value of a obj containing the key amt and setting the value as ( if state[action.id].amt + 1 equal undefined or falsey set it to 1); If state[action.id].amt + 1 is undefined shouldnt we return the value 1 ??

```
[action.id]:{ amt: state[action.id].amt + 1 || 1 } 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'amt' of undefined
```

But this here { id : 1 } works?

```
[action.id] : state[action.id] + 1 || 1
```

Sorry in advance if this a stupid question, but I cant seem to understand why one work and the other one doesn't. I started coding not long ago. I want to get better please help me out.

Thank you

edit:
Sorry I was not being clear on my question.
How come [action.id]:{ amt: state[action.id].amt+1 || 1} is not returning
someID : { amt: 1 } instead return typeError.
But [action.id] : state[action.id] + 1 || 1 return someID : 1 and not a typeError ?
In both situations, I am using || but one gave me an error but the other did not.

Comment: In the code supplied I'm not seeing anywhere that state is being populated apart from the empty object `{}` of `INITIAL_STATE`. So it's no surprise that `state[anyIndex]` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing that result is that the statement

```
[action.id] : state[action.id] + 1 || 1
```

is equivalent to

```
[action.id] : undefined + 1 || 1
```

which becomes

```
[action.id] : NaN || 1
```

and then

```
[action.id] : 1
```

for at least some `action.id`. In other words, `state[action.id] === undefined` evaluates true for at least some `action.id`, but `undefined + 1` is a valid operation in JS even though it's approximately never a good idea to have it happen. Javascript is... like that.

However, the code you're actually trying to run is different!

```
[action.id]:{ amt: state[action.id].amt + 1 || 1 }
```

becomes

```
[action.id]:{ amt: undefined.amt + 1 || 1 }
```

and `undefined.amt` is never legal! (You can neither set, nor retrieve, properties of `undefined`.)

Comment: Thank you CBHacking for showing me each step in code. It really help me understand what I was doing wrong!! Thank you so much!! My head was pounding I couldn't understand why one was working but the other wasnt.

Answer (score 2):

```
[action.id]: { amt: state[action.id]?.amt + 1 || 1 }
```

This should work, but the left side expression will be always truthy even if `state[action.id].amt` is falsy, because you add `1` to it

Thus:

```
[action.id]: { amt: state[action.id]?.amt + 1 }
```

Comment: Mostly right (and upvoted), but "... always be truthy even if `state[action.id].amt` is falsy, because you add `1`" is wrong. There are at least two obvious cases where `state[action.id].amt + 1` can be falsy: `state[action.id].amt === -1` would make the result of the addition 0 (which is falsy), and `state[action.id].amt === undefined` or `state[action.id].amt === NaN` would make the result of the addition be NaN, which is falsy.